# How to use SQL database instead of Access mdb from Aspx

Tags: asp.net

I have the following c# code that loads high scores from access database, how can I adjust this code to use external sql database (System.Data.SqlClient).  Can I enter the connectionString to a simple config.aspx file instead of starting to use a new web.config file ?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!--#include file=config.aspx"-->
<asp:AccessDataSource id="database" Runat="Server" />
<script runat="server">

void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ){
    String id = Request.QueryString["id"];
    String query;
    System.Data.DataView dataView;

    if(scoreRange == "pastDay") {
        query = "SELECT TOP " + noOfScores + " [name], [score] FROM [" + databaseTableName + "] WHERE [gameID] = " + id + " AND [date] >= DateAdd( \"d\", -1, Now() ) ORDER BY [score] DESC, [date] DESC";
    }  else {
        query = "SELECT TOP " + noOfScores + " [name], [score] FROM [" + databaseTableName + "] WHERE [gameID] = " + id + " ORDER BY [score] DESC, [date] DESC";
    }

    database.DataFile = databaseFile;
    database.SelectCommand = query;

    dataView = (System.Data.DataView) database.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

    Response.Write("<HIGHSCORES scoreRange=\"" + scoreRange + "\">");

    for(int i=0;i<dataView.Table.Rows.Count;i++) {
        Response.Write("<RECORD name=\"" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(dataView.Table.Rows[i][0].ToString()) + "\" score=\"" + dataView.Table.Rows[i][1] + "\" />");
    }

    Response.Write("</HIGHSCORES>");
}

</script>
```

Comment: *instead of starting to use a new web.config file*.. I don't understand what you mean by this, can you elaborate?

Comment: this file does not have web.config file assosiated and I prefer not to set up one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that you want to specify the connection string in the `aspx` file. If so then you want something like:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
    id="SqlDataSource1"
    runat="server"
    ProviderName="<%$ Your provider here%>"
    ConnectionString="<%$ You connection string here%>"
    SelectCommand="You select statement here">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Further reading **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**